# jQuery Overflow: Hidden on Parent, Detect if Child is Actually On Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow, hidden, visible

I'm having an issue with this jQuery that is blowing my mind. I've tried three different JS and jQuery functions people suggested online for accomplishing this and can't seem to get anything to work.

I'm trying to hide the class .arrow-up when .first is actually visible on the screen and hide the class .arrow-down when .last is visible on the screen.

Sounds simple enough, right?

Well the parent element has overflow: hidden on it (like most carousels–they really are from hell). Anyone know how to do this? I'd really appreciate any help, JS really isn't my strongest by any means...

Here's my current jQuery–

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".arrow-down").bind("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".vid-list-container").stop().animate({
                scrollTop: "+=300"
            }, 300);

        });
        $(".arrow-up").bind("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".vid-list-container").stop().animate({
                scrollTop: "-=300"
            }, 300);
        });
 });
```

In this, .vid-list-container is the parent with overflow: hidden on it and .first and .last are both inside the container. The arrow classes are both outside of the container.

Built this pen for anyone who wants to play around with it.
http://codepen.io/seancrater/pen/waPNEW

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Notice however that I used opacity:0, so the arrow can still be clicked. You need to change that!

```
function checkDownArrow() {
  setTimeout(function() {
       if($(".vid-list-container").scrollTop() != 0){
          $('.arrow-up').css('opacity',1);
        }
      if(($(".vid-list-container").scrollTop() + $(".vid-item").height()+5) >= $(".vid-item").length * $(".vid-item").height()) {
          $('.arrow-down').css('opacity',0);
        }
      },350); 
}

function checkUpArrow() {
 setTimeout(function() {
       if($(".vid-list-container").scrollTop() == 0){
          $('.arrow-up').css('opacity',0);
        }
      if(($(".vid-list-container").scrollTop() + $(".vid-item").height()+5) < $(".vid-item").length * $(".vid-item").height()) {
          $('.arrow-down').css('opacity',1);
        }
      },350);
 }
 checkDownArrow();
 checkUpArrow();
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".arrow-down").bind("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".vid-list-container").stop().animate({
                scrollTop: "+=173"
            }, 300);
           checkDownArrow();

        });
        $(".arrow-up").bind("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".vid-list-container").stop().animate({
                scrollTop: "-=173"
            }, 300);
            checkUpArrow();
        });
 });
```

Comment: I checked and it worked! However just change the 5 value to something bigger! It is not still the optimal solution, but you can improve it! :)

Comment: Way more functional than the garbage I produced yesterday, I really need to learn more about JS haha

Comment: Just wondering, what does the 5 actually represent in the statement? The number of items?

Comment: Having a rough time making the arrow-down go away on smaller viewports, I'm guess I need to change the way it calculates the distance from the top?

Comment: The 5 is just a number I added because of the margin-top or bottom that divides each item from each other. It was a random number. It is strange though, because when I tried it, it worked on both sides. However, try to get the margin-top, the space between the items and add it instead of 5. It could help.

Comment: It works on both sides in larger viewports but when you shrink it down only the top function is still functional. Maybe it's due to the change in height. I'm gonna play with it and hopefully I can find some numbers that work. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, one final little question. So I found that for mobile viewports (less than 500px wide) I want to set this to be 100 instead of 300. Is there an easy way to do that? Should I just override it with a conditional for that browser width?

if(($(".vid-list-container").scrollTop() + $(".vid-item").height()+300) >= $(".vid-item").length * $(".vid-item").height())

Comment: You could use a resize event to check window width, and instead of a direct value, you use a variable to set the scroll. I think I fixed it to work on different window sizes. Had to change the condition a little bit. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPaJwz

Comment: Notes: the code shown above is very inefficient (reusing jQuery selectors, *same code in both functions!* etc), so can be reduced to less than half and faster. Rather than use `opacity`, which allows for click, you could use `css('visibility', 'hidden')` to hide it but retain the space occupied.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Okay, I see you have a different problem... may I suggest using a different approach? Something like this.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="vid-item">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="vid-item">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-wrapper {width:200px; height:150px; overflow:hidden;}
.inner-wrapper {height:auto; margin-top:0;}
.vid-item {width:200px; height:150px;}
```

JS:

```
    var itemHeight = $('.vid-item').first().height();
    var wrapperHeight = $('.inner-container').height();

    $(".arrow-down").bind("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var margin = parseInt($('.inner-container').css('margin-top'));
        if(itemHeight - margin > wrapperHeight) {
            $('.inner-container').css('margin-top', (itemHeight-wrapperHeight) + 'px');
            $('.arrow-down').addClass('hidden');
        }
        else {
            $('.inner-container').css('margin-top', (margin-itemHeight) + 'px');
        }
        $('.arrow-up').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $(".arrow-up").bind("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var margin = parseInt($('.inner-container').css('margin-top'));
        if(margin + itemHeight >= 0) {
            $('.inner-container').css('margin-top', '0');
            $('.arrow-up').addClass('hidden');
        }
        else {
            $('.inner-container').css('margin-top', (margin+itemHeight) + 'px');
        }
        $('.arrow-down').removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

Comment: `:visible` *does not* check whether they are onscreen/offscreen. Just whether they are hidden (e.g. `display: none`). You need to check the position of the elements instead against the viewport.

Comment: That's the issue I've been hitting, I wish :visible actually did check every type of visibility or at least had the option to without an external option. I'm sure those scripts I saw work, I just have no clue how to use them.

https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible

This seems kind of promising but I still don't know where to start on a script to use it because the documentation is so light...

Comment: I also tried to find code to detect if .first is in it's starting position or if .last moves up there but didn't have any luck finding something for that. It'd have to use the parent element as a reference.

Comment: I updated my answer, i was writing it here on the fly, so there might be some syntax errors, look for the logic of it :)

Comment: So now it gets even more complicated by trying to keep it responsive, guessing this is calculating based on pixel heights? Not sure what I stepped into here by trying to modify a slider, more power to the people that code these things.

Comment: Never got a notification for this comment, but I guess it's never too late to reply :). Yeah, it gets the height of a single element, places all elements vertically and it shows one at a time through a frame by moving it up/down with the `margin-top` property. Anyway, coding these things isn't so complicated, once you get into it, you will do everything yourself, especially this kind of simple gadgets. :)